# Why is my CakePHP login script not working?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am working on my first CakePHP project. I have only ever worked in procedural PHP before and I haven't dealt with anything like the Cake framework, so am having a few teething problems. I'd greatly appreciate help with my login script, which is not working.

My app will be a system for rugby clubs. As such, the login page requires the user to select their club from a drop-down and then enter a password.

**Edited:**

Working as follows:

**/App/Webroot/View/Clubs/login.ctp**

```
  <div class="clubs form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Club'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Please select your club and enter your password'); ?></legend>

        <table>

           <tr> 

                <?php 
                echo $this->Form->input('id', array('label' => 'Club name', 'before' => '<td>', 'after' => '</td>', 'between' => '</td><td>', 'type'=>'select','options'=>$clubs)); 
           ?>
           <tr>
               <?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array( 'before' => '<td>', 'after' => '</td>', 'between' => '</td><td>')); 
           ?>
           </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

**/App/Controller/AppController.php**

```
    public $components = array(
     'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'Club',
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'id',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'clubs', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
            'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'clubs', 'action' => 'login')
        ),
       'DebugKit.Toolbar'
   );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('logout', 'display');
    }
```

**/App/Controller/ClubsController.php**

```
    public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());         
        } 
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid club or password, try again.', 'default', array(), 'auth'));
            $this->set('clubs', $this->Club->find(
                'list', array(
                    'fields' => array('club_name'),
                    'conditions' => array('status' => '2')
                    )
                  )
            );
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->set('clubs', $this->Club->find(
            'list', array(
                'fields' => array('club_name'),
                'conditions' => array('status' => '2')
                )
            )
        );
    }

}

public function logout() {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have been logged out.'));
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add', 'login', 'index', 'logout', 'view');
}
```

Comment: I managed to fix it. I'm not entirely sure how. I'll post the edited, working code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't calling a function named `login`, it's testing for the presence of a property named `login`:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login) {
```

The auth component doesn't have a property named `login`, therefore this test will always be false.

As shown [in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in), you need to call *the function* login to log users in:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
```

Comment: The Cake API says it's a function: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AuthComponent.html#_login

Comment: And says that it doesn't require an argument, the example on the CakePHP tutorial has it like that.

Comment: I have done several times but I don't follow. What is your proposed solution to the code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made this change in my code. My login script now works for a correct password, but it also no longer throws the error if the password is wrong.

Comment: That occurred to me, so I ran /clubs/logout. Instead of getting bounced to the logoutRedirect, I got bounced to the login page with the "Did you really think..." flash set in the AppController. And now I can't login with a correct OR incorrect password. head->desk!

Comment: Sounds like you need the irc channel - you've made your logout function an authed action. Bad idea :)